# QGIS 3 plugin not able to detect python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, qgis

I have installed the custom plugin which was created through plugin builder 3. I just added an `import pymango` statement and have deployed the plugin to QGIS. This gave below error with stacktrace.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 335, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/sample/__init__.py", line 35, in classFactory
    from .sample import custom_plugin
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/sample/custom_plugin.py", line 33, in 
    import pymongo
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 672, in _import
        mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'

Python Path:
/usr/share/qgis/python
/home/ubuntu/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/home/ubuntu/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
/usr/lib/python36.zip
/usr/lib/python3.6
/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/home/ubuntu/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
```

The pymango python library is installed in `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` folder. You can see this folder in python path, still QGIS3.6 desktop application is not able to locate the package. Any solution?

**System details:**

Python version: 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) [GCC 8.2.0]

QGIS version: 3.6.0-Noosa Noosa, 5873452

Ubuntu: 18.04

Comment: Found the answer over here - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314569/qgis-3-plugin-not-able-to-detect-python-packages